# Can you get the max over tensors with different dimensions using pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning, pytorch-geometric

Given a pytorch tensor `t` of length, say, 15, is there a 'nice' way of getting the max values of disjoint subsets of this tensor? Specifically, given a list `l=(5,4,6)` I want the max of the first 5 elements of `t`, then the max of the next 4 elements, and the max of the final 6.

If the elements of `l` are equal, the tensor can be reshaped and the max for each row can be found in a single step. But I can't see a way of doing this nicely when the elements of l are different, without resorting to looping. It would be nice to find a parallelisable way of doing this.

For context, I'm working on a Reinforcement Learning problem in which my states are graphs. An action is just a vertex of the graph. I'm using DQN. When I sample a batch from the buffer, for each graph in the buffer I generate a Q value for each vertex and, for each graph, I want to find the maximum amongst these Q values. But when the graphs have different numbers of vertices I encounter the problem described above: I can't see a way of getting the max Q value for each graph without having to loop through the batch.

Here is an example of how to do this using a loop:

```
# Case when the subset lengths are unbalanced
q_values_tensor = torch.randint(10,(15,1))
lengths_list = [5,4,6]
max_q_values_unbalanced = torch.zeros((1,len(lengths_list)))
tensor_index=0
for list_index, length in enumerate(lengths_list):
    max_q_values_unbalanced[0, list_index] = torch.max(q_values_tensor[tensor_index:tensor_index+length])
    tensor_index += length
```

And an example where the subset lengths are all equal (I'm hoping there might be a solution that is similar to this):

```
# Case when the subset lengths are balanced (what I'd like to replicate)
q_values_tensor = torch.randint(10,(15,1))
lengths_list = [5,5,5]
reshaped_q_values_tensor = q_values_tensor.view(-1,lengths_list[0])
max_q_values_balanced = reshaped_q_values_tensor.max(1)[0]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Ivan - Looping through the list and extracting the max-es from the batch one by one. This works fine but I'm hoping there might be a more elegant way of doing it. The other option that I thought of (but haven't tried) is to pad the tensor (i.e. include dummy values so each max is being taken over the same number of elements), then reshape and take the max over rows. But this would probably require looping as well to insert the dummy elements so isn't necessarily any better.

Comment: You should include a minimal example along with a code implementation even if incomplete and/or non-optimal.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan - have updated the question to include an example implementation